# Ternary operator displays all buttons to be active, instead of just the current button. How do I fix this?

Tags: css, reactjs

Here is my code that is marking all buttons active:

```
<div>
  {
    minAge.map((c,index) => {
      return <button key={index}
                onClick={updateFilters}
                type="button"
                name="min_age"
                className={`${minAge ?'active':null}`}
              >{c}</button>
    })
  }
</div>
```

any suggestions as to how I can correct it so that it only marks the current button as active?

Comment: in any case, you probably meant to use `c` instead of `minAge` in that ternary expression, because that's what contains the individual value, while `minAge` is an array (which is always truthy) => `className={c ? 'active' : null}`

Comment: that doesn't work either.  it still marks all buttons as 'active'

Comment: @Cassiopeia when should the button get the class active?

Comment: ah yes, of course. you need to compare it with some actual value.. otherwise any non-zero value will be marked as active

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing where your current value is stored. But it would be something like `c === currentMinAge`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, and this is what worked:

```
className={`${min_age === c.toString() ?'active':null}`}
```